# Kubernetes service port forwarding to multiple pods

Tags: kubernetes, apache-camel

I have configured a kubernetes service and starts 2 replicas/pods.
Here's the service settings and description.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-integration
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    camel.apache.org/integration: my-integration
  ports:
    - protocol: UDP
      port: 8444
      targetPort: 8444
      nodePort: 30006



kubectl describe service my-service
```

Detail:

```
Name:                     my-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 camel.apache.org/integration=xxx
Type:                     NodePort
IP Families:              <none>
IP:                       10.xxx.16.235
IPs:                      10.xxx.16.235
Port:                     <unset>  8444/UDP
TargetPort:               8444/UDP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30006/UDP
Endpoints:                10.xxx.1.39:8444,10.xxx.1.40:8444
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

What I can see is 2 endpoints are listed, unfortunately only one pod receives events. When I kill the pod, the other one will start receiving events.

My goal is to make 2 pod receive events in Round Robin but don't know how to configure the traffic policies.

Comment: What CNI are you using?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor I have tested with killing the pod that receives events and the other replica start receiving once the first pod is deleted, then a new replica pod gets started. I think the expectation is only one of the pods receive events, if we want to have round robin, we need to have a load balancer to do that.

Comment: Could you answer @gohm'c 's question? Also could you provide an example of your deployment? Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up your cluster?